# Is there an open source management platform for APK files?

Tags: android, content-management-system, open-source

I'm looking for open source platform / Tool that will manage apk files like Google Play Market but private, I need it as a backoffice content management tool (To manage a lot of APKs with different versions).

I didn't find anything like that while searching on Google, any ideas?

Thanks,

Yaniv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestFlight allowed to do this in the past. But due to recent Apple acquisition this is no longer possible.

HockeyApp can also help you with this.

But these aren't cost free.

Crashlytics recently talked about releasing something in this purpose. Will probably be free, at least during the beta phase. http://www.crashlytics.com/blog/from-crashlytics-labs-announcing-our-beta-distribution-tool/

Otherwise if you're a Google Apps user, you can distribute app privately through the Play Store to everybody inside your Google Apps domain.

Comment: Thanks for the info, maybe I will start working on it as a side project :)